# Grails & Netbeans: making changes without rerunning run-app

Tags: grails, netbeans, intellij-idea

Hey all,
I'm just starting with Grails in Netbeans (6.9.1). I got a demo working, but each time i change a groovy file i need to build the project, and then select run (ie the equivalent of "grails build" and "grails run-app"). If there is already an instance running, I need to first shut that instance down.

This seems wrong. It seems like i should be able to just change the groovy file, and it would get automagically reloaded. Isn't that the point of groovy?

Is this actually how it's supposed to work in Netbeans? Without getting into an IDE war, do other IDEs do it better? everyone seems to rave about the Grails support in IntelliJ. Is it worth it?

One last point... I noticed that a regular war maven project no longer automatically reloads on an F11 build. Could this be related?

Thanks

--Matthias

Comment: I always just run the app from the command line, and make changes in my IDE.

Comment: Ok... at least a confirmation that my expectation isn't unreasonable. Let me try reinstalling Netbeans or whacking by .netbeans folder to see if it was just something funky. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not expect to have reloading for all your files even by running your grails app through command line.

Depending on which groovy file you have changed, grails run-time auto-reloading will work or not. Indeed:

- **Files and folders supporting reloading in development mode**: `gsp` files (in view folder), grails `services` (in service folder), `controllers`, `taglibs`, `css`, `i18` `resources`, `javascript` files,  some `config` files (like Config.groovy), `url mappings`. Note that there are some Grails bug when for instance, using spring transactional annotation in Services makes the reloading crashed
- **Files and folders NOT supporting reloading** (and requiring a restart of the application): any code under `src/groovy`, `src/java`, `Domain classes` (under domain directory), some configuration files, changes in **plugins**, any code under *utils* folder (if you have any Codec for instance)

So in your case, if you change a controller groovy file AND NetBeans restarts the application, I recommend you to use a separate command line for running grails application and using the IDE for code changes. The only bad side is that you will not use the NetBeans debugger. 
Actually this is the way I work with Grails and IntelliJ

Comment: Wow... good answer. By "separate command line" you mean run grails from a prompt, ie cygwin or something. Do you have a reference for this info? This seems to say that you can reload domain classes: http://www.grails.org/Auto+Reloading. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. On windows, even with dos command prompt it works. No need of cygwin.

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't have a debugger when running the Grails app from the command line. I have the debugger perfectly working in IntelliJ IDEA even when I'm running the Grails app from the command line inside a VM. That means remotely on another machine.It works perfectly.